# Jquery load multiple template pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've have an issue with jQuery when I try to load several of one template page inside a `div`. I'm trying to replace data in the template using jQuery selector. I need to use the jQuery selector to get the `currency()` to work. Only the last data I insert should kept.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="loanPH"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
//This iterate through the banks to a person that can be several which 
//becomes the issue
$.each(person.bank, function(index, element) {
    $('#loanPH').append($("<div>").load('/Templates/MinSide/loanView.html', null, function() {
        //To be able to use currency it got to be a jQuery object and 
        //not a simple string that I could have appended
        $('#total').html(element.total).currency();
        $('#rate').html(element.rate).currency();
        $('#bankName').html(element.bankName);
    }));
});
```

Template loanView.html:

```
Total: <span id="total"></span><br/>
Rate: <span id="rate"></span><br/>
Bank: <span id="bankName"></span><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use click event for one template upload

> `window.jQuery.click(person.bank, function (index, element) {
>       $('#loanPH').load('/Templates/loanView.html', null, function () {
>         //To be able to use currency it got to be a jQuery object and 
>           //not a simple string that I could have appended
>           $('#total').html(element.total).currency();
>           $('#rate').html(element.rate).currency();
>           $('#bankName').html(element.bankName);
>       });
>   });`

Comment: Thanks for reply. The person.bank is a array I need to iterate through with a for loop which is done using the .each, so I believe click event wont work